# get whole post body within codeigniter controller

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm running `XMLHttpRequest` request like this:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
    name : "123",
    id : 12
});

window.console.log("Submitting: " + data);
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', "http://localhost/index.php/lorem/ipsum", true);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (  req.readyState==4) {
        window.console.log( "Sent back: " + req.responseText );
    }
}
req.send(data);
```

as you can see there's no name for parameter being passed.

now I want to read that JSON data inside `ipsum` function of `lorem` controller.
How can I do this? `$this->input->post();` returns false :(

Comment: i think im arriving late to this, but the content type should be application/json (and yes, i know it will have no effects)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `file_get_contents('php://input')`

Answer (score 3):

even though your turning a JSON Object into string your not assigning a key to the string, what so server side does not have an identifier for your string.

What you should do is:

```
req.send("json=" + data);
```

then in PHP use:

```
$this->input->post("json");
```

To receive data without the need of KV Pairs you can use stdin i suppose.

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

or even using a variable designed for this purpose:

`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`

Comment: thank you for your reply! I know that I can do this like that. I wanted to know if there's another way, w/o identifier. May be someway to receive http requests body.

Comment: Yea of course there is, `fopen("php://stdin","r")` to read raw input, but its not the way forward.